# Arduino - only first object loses its data property value when contained in a collection/array in another object

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, object, arduino

Consider the following code for Arduino. It compiles and runs but does not provide the expected output.

```
class Item {
    private :
        int val;

    public :
        int get(){
            return val;
        };
        void set(int v) {
            val = v;
        };
};

class Sub{
    private :
        Item * items;
        int writeIndex;
    public :
        Sub(){
            writeIndex = 0;
        };
        void addItem(Item * obj) {
            items[writeIndex] = *obj;
            writeIndex++;
        };
        int get(int in) {
            return items[in].get();
        };
};

class Main{
    private:
        Sub * sub;

    public:
        void setSub(Sub * s) {
            sub = s;
        };

        int get(int in) {
            return sub->get(in);
        };
};

Main m;
Sub s;
Item i1;
Item i2;
Item i3;
Item i4;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while(!Serial) {}

    i1.set(4);
    i2.set(5);
    i3.set(6);
    i4.set(7);

    s.addItem(&i1);
    s.addItem(&i2);
    s.addItem(&i3);
    s.addItem(&i4);

    m.setSub(&s);
}

void loop(){
    int v = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        v = m.get(i);
        Serial.println(v);
    }
    delay(10000);
}
```

Output is the following : 
0
5
6
7

But it should print :
4
5
6
7

Why the first Item object seems to loose its assigned value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, actually, you're lucky it prints anything!

Your problem is that you actually do not allocate any memory for your array, if I remove all the `Sub` boilerplate, your code is actually the following:

```
Item i1, i2, i3, i4;
i1.set(4);
i2.set(5);
i3.set(6);
i4.set(7);

// Sub()
Item * items;
int writeIndex;
writeIndex = 0;
// s.addItem(&i1)
items[writeIndex] = &i1;
writeIndex++;
// s.addItem(&i2)
items[writeIndex] = &i2;
writeIndex++;
// s.addItem(&i3)
items[writeIndex] = &i3;
writeIndex++;
// s.addItem(&i4)
items[writeIndex] = &i4;
writeIndex++;
```

thing is, `Item* items` is a pointer that is not defined, and thus contains an unknown value. So when you do `items[writeIndex]`, you're accessing memory at the position of a random value contained in the `items` pointer.

If it "somehow" works, it's that you're lucky enough to have that "random" value being one that looks like it "almost" work, while being totally *wrong*.

In order to fix that situation, you need to allocate memory to the `items` array. Either by giving it a size when created in the stack:

```
#define SUB_LENGTH 5 // store up to 5 values
Item items[SUB_LENGTH]
```

or by allocating memory from the heap:

```
Item* items;
Sub() {
    items = (Item*) malloc(SUB_LENGTH);
}
```

if you opt for the first option, you have to add a max length check in `addItem()`:

```
bool addItem(Item* obj) {
    if (writeIndex >= SUB_LENGTH)
        return false;
    items[writeIndex] = *obj;
    writeIndex++;
    return true;
}
```

if you opt for the second option, you may do the max length check, or reallocate the memory to increase the memory size using [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc). I'm not giving you an implementation example, because if you need to change the size of the array, you might prefer to implement a linked list (or use an already existing [linked list](http://playground.arduino.cc//Code/StackList#.UwJPrqKvCJQ)).

Comment: Thanks. I used a vector implementation found on the arduino forums here : http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,45626.0.html and it works well without too much overload.

Comment: I removed it from the code, but there was an SubItem constructor that added something like Item items[] = {}; The compiler lets me do this, but correct me if i am wrong, but I will not be able to add items using items[0] = something, items[1] = something later on ? Is that it ?

Comment: Vector() : d_size(0), d_capacity(0), d_data(0) {}; What does the part after : mean (i.e. d_size(0),...) is it default values ?

Comment: 1/ well, indeed, `items[] = {}` declares an array of size 0, so you'll run into the same trouble. 2/ why did you changed from the working `vector` based version to the non-working array version? 3/ yes, it's a C++ syntax to assign members in constructors.

Comment: 2/ : I did the opposite !, changed from a non working version of pointers mess to a vector : now it works !. But this code is an oversimplification of a more complex code... and for some reason it did not work with vector... but the "why" is what I have to find on my own.

Comment: C++ concepts are coming back... I did not use C++ for the past 14 years, back then I was programming in C++ with borland... and I understood all this... but since then I have been mainly doing web programming in PHP so all those things like allocating memory and garbage collection are done automatically. I barely remember theses concepts now... so I have to push harder to get back my c++ skills ! :)Anyway, thanks for your help, it is much appreciated. I will close this question now.